# dimension of lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am studying lie algebra myself and question is about finding dimension of lie algebra . While i read Wikipedia link about lie algebra and lie group i saw statement

> Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite-dimensional and it has the same dimension as the manifold $G$

How can i proof this statement actually i have no idea Please firstly give me a hint.

Comment: The Lie algebra can be identified with the tangent space at the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another point of view is that you can consider Lie algebras independently of manifolds. Then a Lie algebra $L$ is just a vector space $V$ with a bilinear product, which is skew-symmetric and satisfies the Jacobi identity. Then $\dim L=\dim V$ is the dimension as a vector space. For example, the Heisenberg Lie algebra $L$ with basis $x,y,z$ and $[x,y]=z$ is $3$-dimensional.

Comment: I think you can't see anything about its dimension just seeing it as a vector space ?

Comment: You can. It is just the dimension of the underlying vector space. For example, the Lie algebra of $SL_n(K)$ is just the vector space of traceless $n\times n$ matrices, which has dimension $n^2-1$ as a vector space.

Comment: ohh i see what you mean but what if it is not so easy for example dimension of   lie algebra of SU(2) ? Is it easy to say also ?

Comment: Yes. It has dimension $3$. $SU(n)$ has the same dimension as $SL(n)$, which was $n^2-1$ (see above). See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group).

Comment: Ok but you need to know they have same dimension . For any lie algebra what is the easy way to find its dimension ? I think in your way you need to find its elements and it is not so easy always  ?